# Is this is an efficient and pythonic way to see if any item in an iterable is true for a certain attribute?

Tags: python

Say you have an iterable sequence of `thing` objects called `things`. Each `thing` has a method `is_whatever()` that returns True if it fulfills the "whatever" criteria. I want to efficiently find out if any item in `things` is whatever.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
any_item_is_whatever = True in (item.is_whatever() for item in items)
```

Is that an efficient way to do it, i.e. Python will stop generating items from the iterable as soon as it finds the first True result? Stylistically, is it pythonic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the built-in function `any()`:

```
any_item_is_whatever = any(item.is_whatever() for item in items)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm relieved. `True in` is ugly.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: It even short-circuits when used with a generator expression, so it actually is quite good.  Using the idiomatic way is of cause both more readable and faster.

Comment: Yeah, the generator short-circuiting part seemed pythonic, but the `True in`... Fair to assume `any` is smart, i.e. short-circuits?

Comment: @Ghopper21: Yes, `any()` also short-circuits.